# undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my Edited details:

I have my controller like,

```
class Enr::Rds::SurvRdsapXrefsController < Enr::Controller

  def index
    @enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xrefs = Enr::Rds::SurvRdsapXref.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
     @enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xref = Enr::Rds::SurvRdsapXref.new
  end

  def edit
    @enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xref = Enr::Rds::SurvRdsapXref.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xref = Enr::Rds::SurvRdsapXref.new(params[:enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xref])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xref.save
        format.html { redirect_to :enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xrefs, notice: "Survey link was successfully created." }
        format.js
        format.json { render json: @enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xref, status: :created, location: @enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xref }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.js
        format.json { render json: @enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xref.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

---

Here is my view form like

```
<%= form_for(@enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xref, :remote => true) do |f| %>

<% if @enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xref.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="validate">
      The form contains <%= pluralize@enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xref.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% @enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xref.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :section %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :section %>
</div>

<%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

When i  click the index page to create a new link, the index page showing error like

NoMethodError in Enr/rds/surv_rdsap_xrefs#index

undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

Thanks for the suppport and please suggest me to rectify the error. I am new to ROR. Thanks

Comment: If the form is being rendered on `index`, you'll have to create a object in the `index` method, as well.

Comment: <%= render 'form' %> Is that you meant ryt?

Comment: Yes, basically, if that's where your form template is.  I was just talking about the code snippet above.  See my new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error reveals that the rendering of the `index` template is causing the error, which means you're rendering the form for the new survey (the code snippet above) in the index template.  This is fine, but if you're going to do that, you'll have to instantiate a new survey in `index`, as well as in `new`.

At the simplest, you could just copy the code in `new` to `index`:

```
def index
  @enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xrefs = Enr::Rds::SurvRdsapXref.paginate(page: params[:page])
  @enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xref = Enr::Rds::SurvRdsapXref.new
end

def new
   @enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xref = Enr::Rds::SurvRdsapXref.new
end
```

To keep your code a bit DRYer you might change where the new instance is created.  A pattern you'll often see is something similar to:

```
before_filter :build_record, :only => [:new, :index]

protected

def build_record
  @survey = YourSurvey.new
end
```

This way you don't even need to write the new/index methods if you don't have any other logic.

Comment: But he wouldn't be getting the 'undefined method errors' error if the view was not being rendered. I don't think that's the issue here.

Comment: It is.  The view is being rendered, but `new` is being called, not `create`.  Edited answer to clarify.  He states in the question that he's updating the `new` template.

Comment: Please have a look of the question now. I edited the question more clearly. Thanks

Comment: I could not understand sorry. I am so new to this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you also set `@survey` in the new action in your controller? The error means that when the view is rendered `@survey` is nil, so there must be a problem with setting that instance variable.

Do you get the error when you go to the 'new' view or when you try to submit the form (create)?

Comment: Then it seems like something is going on in this statement: `Dnr::Pss::Surveyref.new(params[:dnr_pss_survey_ref])` that causes it to fail. Because when the view is rendered @survey seems to be `nil`. Can you post the full log report from the request? Maybe that will tell us more.

Comment: Please have a look of the question now. I edited the question more clearly. Thanks

Comment: The extra information is very good but I can't tell what's wrong. @survey is nil in the view but clearly in the controller it's being set. One thing that looks a little strange: `NoMethodError in Enr/rds/surv_rdsap_xrefs#index`, that seems to indicate the problem happens in the index view. Is it possible to post the full log? Or does it contain sensitive information? This is the only possible problem I can see right now.

Comment: Hi, This controller is based on different controller. I mean the root. For Example, This controller Class Enr::Rds::SurvRdsapXrefsController < Enr::Controller.. is it cause any problem ?

Answer (score 0):

```
The form contains <%= pluralize@enr_rds_surv_rdsap_xref.errors.count, "error") %>
```

This line of the code is the problem. You are lacking a "(" between the pluralize and the @enr...

Explained: RoR thinks that the object is: pluralize@enr... instead of the @ All alone, and he has no errors for this kind of object.